# Promise.all is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

When I asynchronously map an array, Promise.all was supposed to make the function wait until all the promises are resolved. However, Promise.all shows as undefined. Here is my code. Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
router.get("/vehicle_reports/interior-pictures", auth, async (req, res) => {

  const fileKeysObj = await Report.findOne({ orderId: req.params.jobId }, {
    "vehicleInterior": 1
  })
  const fileKeysArray = fileKeysObj.interior
  console.log("fileKeysArray: ", fileKeysArray);

  //Retrieve the files from S3
  const files = fileKeysArray.map(async (item) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: item.fileKey
    }
    await s3.getObject(params, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error()
      }
      else {
        const base64Data = base64Arraybuffer.encode(data.Body)
        const contentType = data.ContentType
        const fileName = item.fileName
        return { base64Data, contentType, fileName }
      }
    })
  })
  console.log( files) //Pending promise
  await Promise.all(files) 
  console.log( files) //Undefined
  res.send(files) //Sends empty array
})
```

Comment: assuming `s3.getObject` you need to return it instead of putting await.. so all files will now contain array of promises.. returning `something inside `await` of map will not store the result in map.. you may need to push them in a diff arary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the inside of the `map` call to look like this.

```
const params = {
  Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
  Key: item.fileKey
}
return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    s3.getObject(params, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        rej('FAILED');
      } else {
        const base64Data = base64Arraybuffer.encode(data.Body)
        const contentType = data.ContentType
        const fileName = item.fileName
        res( { base64Data, contentType, fileName });
      }
    })

});
```

Comment: Even that won't work. He's calling the API with a callback so it's not returning a promise. I'm not even sure if the API WILL return a promise if we don't pass a callback. If it does't then he needs to wrap it in `new Promise()`

Comment: I read the docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property. I can confirm that the API does not return a promise thus is not awaitable. If no callback is supplied it returns an `AWS.Request` object, not a promise

Answer (score 2):

I wish people would stop hyping `async`/`await`. The `await` keyword was designed to work with Promises. And not all asynchronous functions return promises. Lots of APIs (such as S3) use callbacks instead. Also, architectures where you can expect multiple/infinite data return such as servers listening to incoming connection or reading a stream are not good fit for Promises which are basically single-shot. For those EventEmitters are more appropriate.

The `async` keyword does not convert a function to a Promise. It does return a promise but does not have the ability to convert callback based functions to Promises that can be used with `await`. For that you need to use the original `Promise` constructor. Therefore, the correct way to get an array of promises is as follows:

```
const files = fileKeysArray.map((item) => { /* note: async keyword is useless here */
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: item.fileKey
  }


  // We are returning a Promise, so no need to force it to further
  // return a promise by marking this function as "async" above:

  return new Promise((perfectly_fine, oops_something_went_wrong) => {
    s3.getObject(params, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        // Normally people would name this function "reject"
        // but I'm illustrating that the name is really up to you
        // and is not part of the syntax:

        oops_something_went_wrong(err)
      }
      else {
        const base64Data = base64Arraybuffer.encode(data.Body)
        const contentType = data.ContentType
        const fileName = item.fileName

        // This is how you "return" to a promise:

        perfectly_fine({ base64Data, contentType, fileName })
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Now you can await the result. But you are using `await` wrong. The correct way to `await` is as follows:

```
let resulting_files = await Promise.all(files);
console.log(resulting_files);
```

You can also choose to not use await. Instead you can use `.then()`:

```
Promise.all(files).then(resulting_files => {
  // use resulting_files here:

  console.log(resulting_files);
});
```